# Bottom content of the screen are not visible in some phones

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I am developing a flutter app, below is my UI code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints:  BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height),
          child: Container(child: _LoginUI(),),)
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _LoginUI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoginState();
  }
}



class _LoginState extends State<_LoginUI> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  //FIXME When validate error occures, the fields get super small

  

  TextEditingController _phoneNumber = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child:
         Stack(
          fit: StackFit.loose,
          children: <Widget>[
            SafeArea(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                child: Image.asset("assets/images/login_image.png"),
              ),
            ),
            
            Positioned(
              top: 275,
              child: Container(
                height: 600,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                        topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0))),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Flexible(
                          child: Container(
                            margin:
                                EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
                            child: Image.asset(
                                "assets/images/logo.png",
                                width: 200,
                                height: 50),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 40,
                              ),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .90,
                                height: 36,
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: _phoneNumber,
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                                      return 'Please enter some text';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    filled: true,
                                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 2, bottom: 2, left: 8),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                    ),
                                    hintText: "Email",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )),
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 15,
                            ),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 36,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .90,
                              child: TextFormField(
                                controller: _passwordController,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'Please enter some text';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 2, bottom: 2, left: 8),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                  ),
                                  hintText: "Password",
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                            child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 1, left: 10, right: 10),
                                child: FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/password-reset");
                                  },
                                  child: Text("Forgot Password?",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium',
                                          fontSize: 14.0,
                                          letterSpacing: 1.25,
                                          color:
                                              Color.fromRGBO(75, 56, 137, 80))),
                                )),
                          ),
                          Container(
                              margin:
                                  EdgeInsets.only(top: 1, left: 10, right: 10),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .90,
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(75, 56, 137, 80),
                                  textColor: Colors.white,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                      side: BorderSide(
                                          color:
                                              Color.fromRGBO(75, 56, 137, 80))),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "LOGIN",
                                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {

                                    String email = _phoneNumber.text;
                                    String password = _passwordController.text;
                                    
                                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                      loginProcess(email, password);
                                    }
                                  },
                                ),
                              ))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1, left: 10, right: 10),
                        child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/register");
                          },
                          child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                              TextSpan(
                                text: "Not a member yet? ",
                                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',  fontSize: 14.0, letterSpacing: 0.25, color:Color.fromRGBO(75, 56, 137, 80 )),
                              ),
                              TextSpan(
                                text: "Create an Account",
                                style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline,  fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',  fontSize: 14.0, letterSpacing: 0.25, color:Color.fromRGBO(75, 56, 137, 80 ),
                              ),)
                            ]),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
        //child: Image.asset("assets/images/login_image.png"),
        );
  }
```

bELOW Image shows the UI I get I most phones which is correct, and the UI I get in some phones which is inaccurate.

[image]
As you can see, in the inaccurate version, **Botton at the bottom is missing**. This specially happens in `Sony Xperia` series, where its screen size is 4.6 inches and 720x1280 resolution.

The easiest to solve this is to change the value inside the `positioned` to 250 which brings the entire block below the image to more upward. But then that's ugly in some phones because it covers the top image. I have another screen which has the same issue as this, it has more fields. So a solution like setting the `positioned` value into something else will not work.

Whats the best solution to make sure the entire screen is visible in all phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Method would be as follows:

Wrap the `Scaffold` with `SafeArea` then, (this is optional)

If the Widget is correctly positioned in the current device, for  example, the current emulator,
which has a resolution of `480x800`. And the widget is positioned `250px`( an example from your use case)

then it is positioned at approx 31.25% from the top ((250/800)*100).

Then I would use the `MediaQuery.of(Context).size.height*0.3125` for positioning widget form the top.

Now no matter whatever is the height of the phone the widget will always be placed at 31.25% from the top.

Similarly, you can do for `left` position too/

---

My suggestion would also be to do the same with the width and height of the widget so that the size of the widget also be same as per the device screen. and doesn't look too big or small for some devices. Not to every widget but to some.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code but I have no asset files so I changed SizedBox instead.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: _LoginUI(),
    );
  }
}

class _LoginUI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoginState();
  }
}

class _LoginState extends State<_LoginUI> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  //FIXME When validate error occures, the fields get super small

  TextEditingController _phoneNumber = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: LayoutBuilder(builder:
            (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            reverse: true,
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                    // child: Image.asset("assets/images/login_image.png"),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 200,
                      child: Text('Login_image'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                            topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0))),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Flexible(
                              child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 50,
                                  child: Text('LOGO'),
                                ),
                                //Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png",
                                //    width: 200, height: 50),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Form(
                          key: _formKey,
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 40,
                                  ),
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    width:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .90,
                                    height: 36,
                                    child: TextFormField(
                                      controller: _phoneNumber,
                                      validator: (value) {
                                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                                          return 'Please enter some text';
                                        }
                                        return null;
                                      },
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        filled: true,
                                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                                        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            top: 2, bottom: 2, left: 8),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                        ),
                                        hintText: "Email",
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )),
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 15,
                                ),
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  height: 36,
                                  width:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .90,
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    controller: _passwordController,
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                                    validator: (value) {
                                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                                        return 'Please enter some text';
                                      }
                                      return null;
                                    },
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      filled: true,
                                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          top: 2, bottom: 2, left: 8),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                      ),
                                      hintText: "Password",
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                child: Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 1, left: 10, right: 10),
                                    child: FlatButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.pushNamed(
                                            context, "/password-reset");
                                      },
                                      child: Text("Forgot Password?",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontFamily: 'Roboto-Medium',
                                              fontSize: 14.0,
                                              letterSpacing: 1.25,
                                              color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                  75, 56, 137, 80))),
                                    )),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 1, left: 10, right: 10),
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    width:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .90,
                                    child: RaisedButton(
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(75, 56, 137, 80),
                                      textColor: Colors.white,
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                          side: BorderSide(
                                              color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                  75, 56, 137, 80))),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "LOGIN",
                                        style:
                                            Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        String email = _phoneNumber.text;
                                        String password =
                                            _passwordController.text;

                                        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                          // loginProcess(email, password);
                                        }
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                            margin:
                                EdgeInsets.only(top: 1, left: 10, right: 10),
                            child: FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/register");
                              },
                              child: RichText(
                                text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: "Not a member yet? ",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',
                                        fontSize: 14.0,
                                        letterSpacing: 0.25,
                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(75, 56, 137, 80)),
                                  ),
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: "Create an Account",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                      fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular',
                                      fontSize: 14.0,
                                      letterSpacing: 0.25,
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(75, 56, 137, 80),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ]),
                              ),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(height: 400),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
    //child: Image.asset("assets/images/login_image.png"),
  }
}
```